# Alternate chart to performance v/s time for a portal

Tags: user-centered-design, charts, graphs

I am stuck at the point where I have to show the performance of Events (Call, SMS, Internet, and Reg.) v/s Time(ms).

Values can be good bad or medium.

**Here is the older graph which I have to revamp:** 
[image]
As you see they have used this graph. On hover of each dot, details appear.

My options: 
**Option 1**
[image]

**Option 2:** 
[image]

**Option 3:**
[image]

**Option 4**
[image]

Graphs are based on HighCharts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First ask: What is the story you want the data to tell?

**If you're asking:**

- out of the *total events that occurred*, what is the *ratio* of good, bad and medium for each time slice?

If that is the question,  **option 2** is going to give you the clearest picture so far. You see the sum totals in each time slice.

BTW: What does 'Good, bad and medium' mean? How is it quantified?

First, clarify your question: that will get you further towards choosing the correct visualization.

**A thought about the time (x-axis) and direction:**

In most data visualizations, time moves from left to right, past to present.

Here, it looks like you have the opposite: my eyes kept looking for the trend from left to right.

Are you doing this because you have the 'Now' section next to the labels for quick reading?

#### Consider making the time (x-axis) read left to right, with 'Now' on the right

The majority of performance charts showing trend over time will move from left to right:

[image]

[image]

And watch the direction on **[highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update)** for their dynamically refreshing time series:

[image]

Again, the present is on the right.